# Why are my global variables not changing?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, google-calendar-api, client-side

I am new at coding and I am wondering why are my global variables not carrying through.

This is my code in **globals.js** document

```
let bookHour;
let bookTitle; 
let bookDays;
let bookMins;
let startRead;
let cas = new Date()
console.log(cas)
```

on **index.html** I am calling my documents in this sequence

```
<script src='./js/utils/globals.js'></script>
<script src='./js/utils/readingSpeedControler.js'></script>
<script src='./js/app.js'></script>
<script src='./js/utils/onsubmit.js'></script>
<script src='./js/calendar.js'></script>
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
</script>
```

Now I am trying to do the following in my **onsubmit.js** I am changing the variables in my 
**globals.js**.

```
bookTitle  = data.title
bookDays = numberOfDaysNeeded;
bookHour = numberOfHoursNeeded; 
bookMins = numberOfMinNeeded;
startRead = startTime
```

After running **onsubmit.js** user can authorize my app to change his ***google calendar***. The google calendar document (**calendar.js**) should then look at the global variables saved in **globals.js**
but upon looking the values variables remain to be ***undefined***.

I guess I am missing something obvious but I can't seem to find my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your globals aren't being overwritten or wiped in your code. Also make sure the values assigned to your globals in **onsubmit.js** are not undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The mistake was quite obvious. After google auth my app automatically logged me in so, It didn't exactly call functions in calendar.js in which I passed global variables.